# How to get groupdict from multi-line string using regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I tried to get a dictionary from multi-line string using regex, but I have a problem with proper separation of lines.

Here is what I have tried...

```
import re

text = '''\n\n\nName: Clash1\nDistance: -1.274m\nImage Location: navis_raport_txt_files\\cd000001.jpg\nHardStatus: New\nClash Point: 1585.236m, 193.413m'''
clash_data = re.compile('''
    (?P<clash_number>Clash\d+)\n
    (?P<clash_depth>\d.\d{3})\n
    (?P<image_location>cd\d+.jpg)\n
    (?P<clash_status>\w{2:})\n
    (?P<clash_point>.*)\n
    (?P<clash_grid>\w+-\d+)\n
    (?P<clash_date>.*)''', re.I | re.VERBOSE)
print(clash_data.search(text).groupdict())
```

This similar example works well:

```
import re

MHP = ['''MHP-PW-K_SZ-117-R01-UZ-01 - drawing title 123''',
       'MHP-PW-K_SZ-127-R01WIP - drawing title 2',
       'MHP-PW-K_SZ-107-R03-UZ-1 - drawing title 3']

fields_from_name = re.compile('''
    (?P<object>\w{3})[-_]
    (?P<phase>\w{2})[-_]
    (?P<field>\w)[-_]
    (?P<type>\w{2})[-_]
    (?P<dr_number>\d{3})[-_]
    [-_]?
    (?P<revision>\w\d{2})?
    (?P<wip_status>WIP)?
    [-_]?
    (?P<suplement>UZ-\d+)?
    [\s-]+
    (?P<drawing_title>.*)
    ''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
for name in MHP:
    print(fields_from_name.search(name).groupdict())
```

Why doesn't my attempt work like the example?

Comment: Add `r`  prefix to the string literal, there are `\n`s that are not meaningful when `re.X` flag is used. That is, `re.compile('''` -> `re.compile(r'''`

Comment: Thanks, i tried do this before, but it doesn't work.
I got error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working simply because `Pattern.search()` is not finding a match. Based on the working example you are mimicking, you need to also match the characters between the named capture groups that you want in your output dict (so that the entire pattern returns a match).

Following is an example using `.*\n.*` as a bit of a brute force way to bridge the gap between your capture groups by matching any non-newline characters after the last capture group, then matching the newline, and then matching any non-newline characters that precede the next capture group (you will probably want to be more precise than this, but it demonstrates the issue). I only included your first 3 groups because I wasn't following what you intended with the regex in your `<clash_status>` group.

```
import re

text = '\n\n\nName: Clash1\nDistance: -1.274m\nImage Location: navis_raport_txt_files\\cd000001.jpg\nHardStatus: New\nClash Point: 1585.236m, 193.413m'

clash_data = re.compile(r'(?P<clash_number>Clash\d+).*\n.*'
                        r'(?P<clash_depth>\d.\d{3}).*\n.*'
                        r'(?P<image_location>cd\d+.jpg)', re.I | re.VERBOSE)

result = clash_data.search(text).groupdict()

print(result)
# OUTPUT
# {'clash_number': 'Clash1', 'clash_depth': '1.274', 'image_location': 'cd000001.jpg'}
```

Comment: Thanks for clear answer.
I'm beginer that is why I mimick some solution which I found on the internet, now I can delve into the problem.